# SQL Extended Properties and BCS Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sql, sharepoint, properties, sharepoint-2010, bcs

I know you can connect to SQL Databases using BCS in SharePoint 2010 but what I want to know is if instead of connecting the table information with SharePoint, is it possible to import/connect the **Extended Properties** of the tables in SQL to SharePoint???

In other words, how can I view extended properties of SLQ Database tables in SharePoint? I know you can view the data, but what about extended properties? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing would be to make a view in the database with this sql:

```
select tab.table_name, ex.name, ex.value
from sys.extended_properties ex
inner join information_schema.tables tab on ex.major_id = object_id(tab.table_name)
```

Then it should be just a standard bcs connection (though i haven't tested it)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this early next week, hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that it is not editable, it is just a VIEW (plus, Value does not appear in SharePoint since it is an Object (complex) and not supported by SP).